# richfaces 3.3.3 rich:calendar how to set input field to today date?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the following code:

```
      <rich:calendar id="DocFromDate" locale="bg" firstWeekDay="1"
                 value="#{ioPageBeanParam.editBean.data['DocFromDate']}"
                 datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
```

This displays empty input field and calendar icon.
I would like to pre-fill the input field with today's date.

Searched trough [documentation richfaces 3.3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html)

But did not find the way to get and set currentDate. Is it possible in this component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize it in your bean. In the constructor of your bean set the value to today.

Comment: It would be better to initialize it in `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: I'm new in Java and richfaces and have to discover what bean is responsible for the calendar, if I put @PostConstruct in JDeveloper got message to import some library. Anyway, I found in another bean initialization `code    public Map<String, Object> getInitializationParameters() {
      Map<String, Object> initParams = super.getInitializationParameters();
      initParams.put(DOCUMENT_DOC_FROM_DATE_ATTR, Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
      return initParams;
    } `

Comment: There is no bean 'responsible' for the calendar. It is you who decide. The bean where you get you value from. In this case: ioPageBeanParam

Comment: Correct.  The application I have to maintain is very complicate. Actually it has parameter ` <ui:param name="ioPageBeanParam" value="#{documentsPageBean}"/> ` so the actual bean is documentsPageBean and so on with other issues.